# Story about a boy from a cold world, who comes to Earth through a portal

Tags: story-identification

Story about a boy coming through a portal to Earth. The Sun burns him and a girl hides him, until he breaks free and returns to his own world. She follows him to a cold world, where she is cold the whole time.

I think the male character is called Charn.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this a book, short story, movie or animation? Also, roughly when did you see this, and can you think of any more details to add? The more info you can provide, the better your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: I read it in 1997, think it was late 80s, early 90s - it is a novel. I remember when she followed him to his world (without his knowledge) they found an ancient way to be together (some sort of trial). The book wasn’t set in modern times, think industrial age probably

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is only a partial match, but the [novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5388.Through_The_Dragon_s_Eye) of *[Through the Dragon's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Dragon%27s_Eye)* probably follows the same plotline as the TV series, which has Charn as a character in a cold world, followed by one of the protagonists.

> Fortunately, the inability to read also afflicts Charn, allowing Jenny to display a written message to her friends when Charn forbids her to divulge his presence (She tricked Charn into allowing her to knit a scarf due to the cold of Pelamar, drawing out a pattern that actually spelled out "HELP! CHARN!" without him knowing, which she could then show to the others over a video phone). Although Gorwen is able to defeat Charn, he is dangerously weakened, nearly killing himself before the last Veeton is discovered and the Veetacore restored. Although the show ends with the children returning to their school at apparently the moment they left, the presence of their notebooks and three miniature versions of the Veetons they recovered proves that the experience was genuine.

Comment: Hi thank you for helping, but nope. The book is young adult fantasy - I googled this book and looked more for younger kids